# Do I need curtailment letter to apply for Further leave to remain in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, residency

I was living in the UK under a tier 2 General work visa, but left my job. I am planning to apply for Further leave to remain as a spouse of a UK citizen (my wife is english), but I haven't received a curtailment letter yet, and I understand that this can take a while, or may not even happen unless I request it by mail. I would rather just get through the process now rather than wait until some indeterminate time when I receive the letter, but I have been told when I called the Immigration service that I needed the letter before I book or send my application for FLR. Anyone know if that is true, ie. do I absolutely need the letter, or can I just go on and apply now ?
thanks

Comment: I've never heard of anyone needing any curtailment letter for any application of any kind, ever. Apply now. Don't wait at all. Supply the necessary documentation as specified by the guidance. The people at the immigration service are notorious for giving inaccurate and sometimes flat out incorrect information.  I have literally called them 3 different times about the same situation, and gotten 3 different answers. And they do not take any responsibility for their 'advice' no matter how catastrophic the results.

Comment: That said, a few questions: When did/does that visa expire? When did you get married? How long has it been since you left your job? This will help give a clear picture of your current immigration situation.

Comment: Thanks ouflak, that was my feeling as well but I thought I would check. 
My wife is a british citizen, we were married several years ago, in Canada. We came over to the UK about 6 months ago, and I left my job about 3 weeks ago. Theoretically my tier 2 work visa would have been valid for 6 years, if I had stayed in the job. I am planning to apply as FLR(M), she has the necessary salary for me to be eligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can apply right now if you like. No curtailment letter necessary.